# SQL tag based search with logical AND behaviour rather than OR

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a mysql database set up with the following tables

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Company(
name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
description VARCHAR(512) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(name)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CompanyTag(
companyName VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
tag VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(companyName, tag)
);
```

leading to a CompanyTag table that looks like this

```
Company            Tag
someCompany1      first
someCompany1      second
someCompany1      third
someCompany2      first
someCompany2      second
someCompany3      first
```

When the search is "first second third" only someCompany1 should be returned. When the search is "first second" only someCompany1 and 2 should be returned.
When the search is "first" someCompany1, 2 and 3 should be returned.

At the moment I can search the companies with one or more words by performing the following query

```
SELECT name, description, location, website, categoryName FROM Company 
INNER JOIN CompanyTag ON CompanyTag.companyName = Company.name
WHERE tag REGEXP ?;

where ? is "^(.*first.*|.*second.*|.*third.*)$"
```

However as you would expect this has the effect of ORing the tags

What can I do to the structure of the database or query to enable me to AND the tags instead ie. Get all results where the company is tagged with first, second and third as opposed to first or second or third.

Edit: Perhaps the question was not quite clear. It is more of an SQL problem because each tag associated with a company is a separate entry in the CompanyTag table. Therefore I don't think that it can be solved by changing the regex as it is to my knowlege only evaluated against a single entry in the table and not all the entries joined together.

Comment: Are the tags supposed to be in a certain order?

Comment: No the tags do not need to be in a certain order

Comment: Please edit your question and give examples of tags.

Answer (score 1):

I would run screaming from using regex for this problem.

If you have a unique tags and companies and unique company-tag combos, which it looks like you do, you can easily search for companies with the title of the tag.

OR logic:

```
  SELECT c.* 
    FROM company c 
    JOIN companyTag ct ON ct.companyName = c.name
   WHERE ct.tag IN (:1,:2,:3)
GROUP BY c.name;
```

AND logic:

```
  SELECT c.* 
    FROM company c 
    JOIN companyTag ct ON ct.companyName = c.name
   WHERE ct.tag IN (:1,:2,:3)
GROUP BY c.name
  HAVING count(*) = 3;
```

**UPDATE**

I'd probably go a bit further and create a separate `tag` table `(id,title)` with a unique on `title`, give `company` an `id` and a unique `name` and make `companyTag` a many-many `(companyId, tagId)` with a unique across both fields.

Comment: Using this how do I apply a LIKE or REGEXP to the IN operator? So that the it matches the tag "bananas" if I type "ban".

Comment: Short answer is you cannot.. but you can split out the IN with the clunkier OR syntax if you want.

Comment: If "ban" needs to match "banana", then Edit the Question !  Otherwise `IN` solutions are much better than `REGEXP solutions.

Comment: @RickJames This was implicit given the original regex was "^(.*first.*|.*second.*|.*third.*)$" and not "^(first|second|third)$"

Comment: Well, your regexp is overkill.  `^` and `.*` cancel each other out.  `first|second|third` would be the way to say "first/second/third `anywhere` in the string".  This would be the equivalent on IN:  `^(first|second|third)$`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex:

```
^(?=.*first.*)(?=.*second.*)(?=.*third.*).*$
```

It should check for all 3 conditions, `first` AND `second` AND `third` must be present in the string. These words do not have to be in a certain order.

You can check how this [regex works on the regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/kY8tF3/2).

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have edited the question to attempt to make the problem more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that a regular expression is the best approach.  Assuming you are not storing multiple delimited tags in the field `tag`, just use `in`:

```
SELECT c.name, c.description, c.location, c.website, c.categoryName
FROM Company c INNER JOIN
     CompanyTag ct
     ON ct.companyName = c.name
WHERE tag in ($first, $second, $third)
```

This has the advantage that the `where` clause can take advantage of an index.

Assuming you want all tags in the company, then add `group by` and `having`:

```
SELECT c.name, c.description, c.location, c.website, c.categoryName
FROM Company c INNER JOIN
     CompanyTag ct
     ON ct.companyName = c.name
WHERE tag in ($first, $second, $third)
GROUP BY c.name, c.description, c.location, c.website, c.categoryName
HAVING count(distinct tag) = 3;  -- Note:  "3" here depends on the number of tags
```

If you prefer the regular expression approach, you can, of course, use that instead of `in` for the `where` clause.

Comment: Dammit Gordon! Just beat me to it!

Comment: So should this work? SELECT c.name, c.description, c.location, c.website, c.categoryName
FROM Company c INNER JOIN
     CompanyTag ct
     ON ct.companyName = c.name
WHERE tag LIKE '^(.*first.*|.*second.*|.*third)$'
GROUP BY c.name, c.description, c.location, c.website, c.categoryName
HAVING count(distinct tag) = 3;  -- Note:  "3" here depends on the number of tag